# Where can I find a conclusive list of features in .net 4?

Tags: .net-4.0

I've searched the web, and I can only find marketing material on .net 4.

I would like a more detailed look at the new features from a developers point of view, not high level MS business marketing.

Can someone point me in the right direction please.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Scott Gu has a nice post which summarizes the new features in .NET 4 as well as visual studio 2010 along with ASP.NET MVC 2, and at the bottom he also has linked his blog posts that contain info about new .NET 4 features

http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2010/04/12/visual-studio-2010-and-net-4-released.aspx

**Edit:** I searched for this, but couldn't find it in the first go (MSDN post), nubm has also referred this in his answer.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms171868.aspx